# Create simple update query with table joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT
  c.LastName
 ,c.FirstName
 ,c.ClientStatusULink
FROM Client c
  JOIN Vets_Active_Clients vac ON vac.Clientid = c.ClientID
```

Which results in some data:

```
LastName    FirstName   ClientStatusULink
--------    ---------   -----------------
Battle Jr   Sam         10000000
Bauder      Bill        10000000
Sabir       Mo          10000000
```

I need to create an update query to update the "ClientStatusULink" to "333".  I have the following UPDATE query, but it runs forever.  What is wrong with this?

```
UPDATE Client
SET ClientStatusULink = '333'
FROM Client c
  JOIN Vets_Active_Clients vac ON vac.Clientid = c.ClientID
```

Thank you

Comment: @ISHIDA the condition is in the JOIN.

Comment: Side note: It's good practice to explicitly state the kind of join, in this case, "INNER JOIN", just so there's zero chance for confusion. It's also customary to use the alias you define in the UPDATE ("UPDATE c"). Also: Is there a trigger on the table? A ton of indexes? ANY indexes?  This will basically update all rows in Client that have associated rows in Vets_Active_Clients... if there are a ton of rows, it'll take a while.

Comment: @pbmAustin - Thank you.  I clarified the JOIN to INNNER JOIN and used the alias on my UPDATE statement (from Update Client to Update c).  Ran it again and it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the alias defined in the `from`:

```
UPDATE c
    SET ClientStatusULink = '333'
    FROM Client c JOIN
         Vets_Active_Clients vac
         ON vac.Clientid = c.ClientID;
```

If you don't use the alias defined in the `FROM`, then the reference to `Client` in `UPDATE` is a different reference from the `FROM` clause -- it is essentially a self-cross join.

Comment: beat me by a minute!

Answer (score 1):

Try using an alias for your join:

```
UPDATE c
SET ClientStatusULink = '333'
FROM Client c
  JOIN Vets_Active_Clients vac ON vac.Clientid = c.ClientID
```

Answer (score 0):

the query is correct.
maybe Client table is in use. you can check it in Activity Monitor and find which query blocked client table.
the other reason that can cause these kinds of issues is your tables are huge.

Comment: Thank you for the verification.  Perhaps it was in use, but it seems I need to use the alias used in the FROM statement.  I made those minor changes as indicated in other replies and it ran correctly and quickly.  Kind Regards.